# Twitter's Rate Limit, bypass?

Tags: twitter

I was about to code a mobile web twitter client with a lot of functions in mind, but I was going through their API, noticed they limit requests to 350 per hour, and they've also disabled white-listing of IP addresses. This doesn't seem feasible for a large scale app, is there anyway to bypass. Or just dump the entire project. Programming lang is chiefly PHP.

Comment: ConTact_Twitter(Me); Twitter(Redirect,Me,API); They'll refer me to their API.

Comment: Yes, contact Twitter. Ask for your limit to be lifted or increased. They have the power to change your limit if they see fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats 350 requests per hour per user, not global per application.

By that what I mean is, if your application is used by 100 users, each one of those users has their own limit for their account.

So your app can refresh around once every 10 seconds or so, that seems plenty to my mind.